# It's possible send notification while app work in foreground

Tags: android

Well, I'm developing an app on the Android Studio, and I would like to know if it's possible for example, the app are working in foreground and it's a new day, and my recyclerview are full or empty, It's possible send a notification to inform the user the state of the recycler view?

```
   @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    final String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    holder.edit_Cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.edit_pencil.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.thrash_delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.edit_save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.RedMate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.YellowMate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.GreenMate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (profiles.get(position).getTaskdate().equals(currentDateandTime)) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationDialog();
        }
        if ((profiles.get(position).getColor().equals("Amarelo"))) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_ground_questio);
        }
        if (profiles.get(position).getColor().equals("Verde")) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_bck_tasks);
        }
        if (profiles.get(position).getColor().equals("Vermelho")) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_bck_tasks);
        }
        holder.taskname.setText(profiles.get(position).getTaskname());
        holder.tasklocal.setText(profiles.get(position).getTasklocal());
        holder.taskdate.setText(profiles.get(position).getTaskdate());
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    }
}
```

-------------------------------------»«---------------------------------------

```
     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void notificationDialog() {
       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
   context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "tutorialspoint_01";
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel 
     notificationChannel = new 
     NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My 
 Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Sample Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle("Tasks")
            .setContentText("You have tasks for today!!!")
            .setContentInfo("Information");
    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Now I see the notification, but just when I'm on the present activity, the real problem to me now is to know how put her work on foreground, when the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        context.startForegroundService(intent);
    } else {
        context.startService(intent);
    }
```

in Service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // your notification
    startForeground(id, notification);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    ExampleRunnable runnable = new ExampleRunnable(0);
    new Thread(runnable).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {
    int seconds;

    ExampleRunnable(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (seconds == 0) {
            int seconds = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60;
            if (seconds == 0) {
                sendNotification();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just one example

Comment: Hi, tanks for answering, can you explain in detail the code please, im newbie on android, and well, I'm a little bit confused with the code that you post. thanks again. :)